# redirect parked domain to another domain subfolder showing correct urls

Tags: .htaccess, dns

i have 2 domains:
- domain1.org
- domain2.org

i have installed wordpress in http://**domain1**.org/wordpress and i need that users enter with http://**domain2**.org

Currently my htaccess is(based on other posts readed here):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain2\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.org/wordpress/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

this works but always show in the links the domain1 url:

http://**domain1**.org/wordpress/category/furniture/

and in the browser bar i have http://www.**domain2**.org

Is the htaccess wrong? i have domain2 with godaddy and i'm doing a masked forward.Maybe i should park it?

thk.

Comment: solved. It was a domain problem with forwarding.Is there a way to delete this post? I think it isn't useful for helping others.

Comment: There should be a "delete" link below tags (next to "link", "edit" etc) -- although I'm not 100% sure on this as have not asked any questions yet :P

Answer (score 0):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   
# tell mod_rewrite to activate and give base for relative paths

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?PARKED.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PARKED/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /PARKED/$1 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?PARKED.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ PARKED/index.php [L]

# for main domain

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```